# Is AUC a good metric for evaluating the performance of a multi-class classification?

Tags: statistics, cross-validation, multiclass-classification, model-evaluations

Considering the definition of `AUC` (Area Under Curve), is that a reliable performance metric for a multi-class (**30-40 classes**) classification problem?

Comment: AUC is a binary classification metric, I do not think you can use it for multi-class classification

Comment: @RobinNicole You are right but it also has been suggested for multi-class classification by binarizing techniques.

Comment: What do you mean by binarizing technics ? If you have a link I am really interested :)

Comment: @RobinNicole I think reading this article can be helpful for you: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Comment: Which technique do you use for calculation of TPR and FPR? micro-averaging or macro-averaging?

Comment: @pythinker If you know any techniques for this purpose which makes AUC reliable for multi-class classification, please suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

No - AUC (Area Under Curve) can not be used directly to assess the performance of multi-class classification.

If you want to use AUC, it is necessary to binarize the output. Either each class as to be compared against each other class or 1 class versus the rest.